# Broken Search Builder

Tags: search

just upgraded to 5.28.3.

Thing is, my search builder is looking like this now - can't select a field anywhere :/

[image: Search Builder]

Any Ideas?

Thx & Regards

Comment: Do you get any js errors in browser console?

Comment: just confirmed it looks fine on dmaster.demo

Comment: Only error in my browser console is: Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid assignment left-hand side

Comment: does dmaster.demo have search builder extension perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like i f*cked it up myself:
Some days ago we created a new contact subtype and renamed it afterwards.
Since renaming didn't work out as planned and some DB-Entries stayed behind, i changed em manually. Guess what, i had a typo somewhere.
Changed it and the search builder is back to normal.

Sorry for bothering you and Thanks for your help.